# bootstrap-datepicker-rails, show calendar only on clicking calander-icon(not on text field)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I,m using `bootstrap-datepicker-rails` gem for date picker and want to shoe calender only on icon click(not on clicking text filed).
Write Now I'm using in my form:

```
= form_for (ServiceExp.new), :remote => true do |s|
  %ul
    %li
      = s.label :position
      = s.text_field :position
    %li
      = s.label :start_date
      %p
        From
    %li
      .input-append.date.datepicker
        = s.text_field :start_date, :class =>"input-mini"
        %span.add-on
        .calander-icon        
      To
      .input-append.date.datepicker
        = s.text_field :end_date, :class => "input-mini"
        %span.add-on
          .calander-icon
    %li
      = s.label :description
      = s.text_area :description

  = s.submit 'Save',:class => "btn btn-primary"
```

And in javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Here, Calendar shows on both text field and icon because class `datepicker` on top of both. If use this class only on icon than it show calender only on icon click but not adding value on text field. How can I achieve that one. please give any suggestion !!

Answer (score 0):

Add `:"data-date-format" => 'dd-mm-yyyy', :'data-date' => '12/2/2013' # default date`

To div container containing input box and span.

Like

```
%li
      .input-append.date.datepicker{:"data-date-format" => 'dd-mm-yyyy', :'data-date' => '12/2/2013'} # default date
        = s.text_field :start_date, :class =>"input-mini"
        %span.add-on
        .calander-icon
```